# call my javascript function in the change event of a text box

Tags: javascript, ascx, ajaxform

I want to trigger a call to a function ,when any change is done in the text box to validate the input .
I don't want to add an inline call , rather want to add the code in the script block .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#LocationName").change(validateLocationName);

    });

 function validateLocationName()
    {
        var formAddress = contractAddress.getData();
        formAddress.LocationName = $("#LocationName").val();
        if (  validate condition) {

            --- add error or etc
            return false;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

attached the code i am trying to use , but the function does not get called . Any help will be appreciated

Comment: just move your function inside your `$(document).ready` _function_ !

Answer (score 0):

Your code, if stripped down to just call the function, works like below. Just make sure you have included the necessary jQuery script and also that you are not getting any other error. e.g if `getData()` is actually working and `if` statement has valid check like `if (formAddress.LocationName == $("#LocationName").val())`

```
<textarea id="LocationName"></textarea>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#LocationName").change(validateLocationName);
    });

    function validateLocationName() {        
        alert($("#LocationName").val());
    }
</script>
```